# Fill in values of $x$ and $y$ in Jacobian

Tags: python, function, sympy, diff

I wrote a function in Python to calculate the Jacobian for a set of two non-linear equations.
How can I fill in values for $x$ and $y$?
This is my code:

```
x= Symbol('x')
y= Symbol('y')

F = [3*x**2+2*y**2-25,2*x**2-y-15]

def jacobiaan(F):
    j11 = diff(F[0], x)
    j12 = diff(F[0],y)  
    j21 = diff(F[1],x)
    j22 = diff(F[1],y)
    jac = [[j11,j12],[j21,j22]]
    return jac

print(jacobiaan(F))
```

Comment: what do you mean "fill in values"? you mean evaluate for a certain x and y?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes, I want to evaluate the Jacobian in (1,1)

Comment: assign the result of the function to a variable `J=jacobiaan(F)` then you can use `.subs` to substitute x and y for their values. `J.subs({x:1, y:1})`, the same you would do for F.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I already tried that, but it gives me an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'subs'

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I also tried assigning the elements of the Jacobian to a function, like this:     f1 = lambda x: jac[0][0]
    return jac, f1(1), but the output still gives me the function 6*x, not evaluated in x=1

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions are sitting in a list of lists. If you want to deal with them that way you either have to assign values *before* creating the list of *after*. To do it before, pass those values as parameters `jacobiaan(F, xval, yval)` and do something like `j11 = diff(F[0], x).subs(x, xval)`. To do so afterwards you have to traverse the lists:

```
>>> lol = [[x, x + 1], [x + 2, x + 3]]
>>> [[i.subs(x, 1) for i in j] for j in lol]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

But it might be easier to just convert the list-of-lists to a Matrix and let it do the traversal:

```
>>> Matrix(lol).subs(x,1)
Matrix([
[1, 2],
[3, 4]])
>>> _.tolist()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And easier still, to let SymPy compute the Jacobian:

```
>>> Matrix([x, x**2 + y]).jacobian((x, y))
Matrix([
[  1, 0],
[2*x, 1]])
>>> _.subs(x,2)
Matrix([
[1, 0],
[4, 1]])
```

With the final approach, you get the data into a SymPy object from the start.